# React-Redux: Where do I put a side effect that uses part of a reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

*I know not to put side effects in reducers, and I know there are lots of great explanations about how to handle async actions. I have read them. I have a specific question I'm stumped on. Thanks!*

I have `state.largeObject` which is an object with many entries. I have a reducer that does some complex logic and merges the result into `state.largeObject` like so:

```js
export const myReducer = (state, { input }) => {
  const largeObject = doSomethingComplex(input)
  // other logic that uses largeObject

  return {
    ...state,
    largeObject: {
      ...state.largeObject,
      ...largeObject
    }
  }
}
```

I want to save the result of `doSomethingComplex(input)` to the server. **Where do I put the side effect?** EDIT: without duplicating `doSomethingComplex` which is still needed for other logic in the reducer.

- I can't put it in `myReducer` or `doSomethingComplex` since they are pure.
- I can't put it in Redux middleware, as that only has access to the action and the state as a whole. I don't want to call `doSomethingComplex` both in the reducer and in the middleware.
- I don't want to move it into an action-creator, since that would force a lot of pure functionality into a thunk, making it harder to compose.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, your question is missing too much details on what is the side-effect (is it even a side-effect?) and why you can't put it where it's usually placed. So really, we can't help much more than to say what has already been said, which is: it's an anti-pattern, but do what you want!

Comment: The side effect is to send the result of `doSomethingComplex` to the server, as mentioned. I agree that placing a side effect in the reducer is an anti-pattern, hence the question of where to do it without repeating `doSomethingComplex`.

Comment: Then it should be placed in an action creator (a simple one if you don't need to wait for the response, or thunk, sagas, etc otherwise) and the question becomes: _How to compose actions or how to make generic actions?_ And then include a [mcve] of the action that you're saying is harder to compose with a simple situation that needs that composition.

Comment: Thanks, although the question more has to do with how to avoid calling `doSomethingComplex` both in the reducer and in the action-creator. The reducer needs `largeObject` for other logic, and the action-creator needs `largeObject` to send to the server.

Comment: Please demonstrate why a simple action creator does not work for you. e.g. `const myAction = (input) => { const largeObj = doSomethingComplex(input); /* any side-effect here */ return {type: 'MY_ACTION', payload: largeObject}; };` then both the action creator and the reducer has access to the object without calling it twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Middleware, thunks, and store subscription callbacks are all valid places to do that:

- It's fine to have some saving logic as part of a thunk.  Thunks are a type of middleware, and that's where side effects are supposed to live in general.
- You could have a custom middleware that looks for the specific action type that results in this change, or checks to see if this chunk of state has changed, and makes a call to the server after the state has been updated
- You could have a store subscribe callback that checks to see if this chunk of state has changed and makes a call to the server

Based on the way you phrased things, I'm not sure if you're looking to send *only* the result of that call to the server, or the result of doing `{...state.largeObject, ...largeObject}`.

Comment: Only `largeObject`. Otherwise I could send the whole state or a slice of the state at many points.

Comment: I ended up storing the new `largerObject` to a new state variable `syncQueue`. Then I added a custom middleware that creates the side effect and clears the `syncQueue`. Reducer stays pure and `doSomethingComplex` is not repeated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most suitable approach in my opinion would be moving the whole *reducer* logic (your `doSomethingComplex` function) to the server side.

So all what you'd have to do is dispatching the action and sending required arguments to the API. In case of a success response, you'd dispatch the *success* action, call `myReducer` and save the result in the store.

**However**, if you really want to keep this logic on the front side, you'd have to use a middleware - thunks or sagas (I prefer sagas).

```
// some pseudo code //

dispatch the action
- inside the middleware - 
  call doSomethingComplex() // called once and stored in some variable
  dispatch action that will call the reducer and store the result
  call API with the result
```

But still I'd recommend the first solution since that (the second) approach will work, but may break the proper data flow.

**Edit**: some final thoughts - if you really want to keep those calculations on the front-end side, consider following strategy:

- dispatch the action
- inside middleware (thunks or sagas) call `doSomethingComplex` function
- call the API with the *stuff* that `doSomethingComplex` returned
- **return** the *stuff* - that `doSomethingComplex` returned - from the API as the *success* response
- call success action with the *stuff* and invoke the reducer that will save it in the store

This is how the proper data-flow can be kept alive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately moving the logic to the server is not an option. Regardless, I’m curious anyway about a client-side solution.

Comment: Your suggestion doesn’t solve the primary issue of how to avoid calling `doSomethingComplex` twice: once in the reducer and once where the side effect is made.

Comment: @RaineRevere Well, I just called that function once, inside middleware.

Comment: @RaineRevere you could also isolate the complex logic that leads to `largeObject` from the side-effect itself and just use that complex (side-effect-free logic) function twice, until you can measure that it has a noticeable impact on performance (which was not demonstrated in the question description yet).

Comment: @EmileBergeron Fair point. Let’s assume it does affect performance though.

Comment: @EmileBergeron and Raine - it doesn't change the fact that this is... wrong. An anti-pattern as Emile said. Doing calculations on the front-end side then storing it on the front as well as on the backend side breaks the data flow. Who knows what can happen between sending the call to the API and successfully storing it in the API? What certainty do you actually have that the data stored in the API is **exactly** the same as this one stored on the front side?

Comment: I’m not sure, but that’s not my question. Substitute another side effect besides server-side storage.

Comment: @RaineRevere I just dropped you some final thoughts before going to bed. Gn